# Test Class for Process Instance History

Tags: approval-step, approval-history

I have a class containing the below part of code in it for the Approval Process. I have no clue on how to cover this in my Test Class.

```
 for (ProcessInstanceHistory ps: qs.ProcessSteps) {

  if (ps.ProcessNode.name != null){
```

Here qs is an Quote object instance. Anybody having any idea on how to cover this in the Test class as I didn't find anything on this in any forum yet.

TIA.